# Binding Model to Normal Grid Not DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, grid

So I've been looking for a way to bind a Itemssource to grid

```
<Grid></Grid>
```

the normal Grid, I am aiming to build my own DataGrid with my functionality and style, is it possible to achieve this ? Is it possible to convert this code to normal Grid

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Imported"  VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Listt}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        ColumnWidth="*">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Company" Binding="{Binding Company}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="FullName" Binding="{Binding FullName}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Now if this is not possible can I change(override) the DataGrid behaviors like for example if I double clicked a row in the DataGrid a message will show up saying"You just double clicked a row".

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Check customcontrols. You can create a customcontrol derive from DataGrid and override the double click.